# What does "%{__install}" mean in terms of rpm spec?

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Maybe it's very stupid question but I can't find out the answer.
I've neverr tried to write a spec file for rpm package until today. I found an example of spec and I see a lot of `%{__install}` thinks in the `%install` section. As far as I understand by the syntax it's a king of makros. But there is no defenition for it in the spec files. In my example it looks like this:

```
%install
%{__install} -pD -m 644 $RPM_BUILD_DIR/my-project-%{version}/deploy/my-project.service $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/lib/systemd/system/my_project-emperor.service
```

I also seen a lot of examples with this macros in other spec-s I've found. Like
[this](https://git.sgu.ru/oldssu/ash-virt-platform/commit/3bbf830a7f0fee5e84090ff44bfb227ed89b68bb) or [that](https://gist.github.com/uorat/07ce41773e944bc4f3d3e1916fcba487). They have the same syntax:

```
%{__install} -s %{name} %{buildroot}%{_sbindir}/
%{__install} -c -m 644 examples/acl-content-sw.cfg %{buildroot}%{_sysconfdir}/%{name}/%{name}-acl-content-sw.cfg.example
%{__install} -c -m 644 examples/auth.cfg %{buildroot}%{_sysconfdir}/%{name}/%{name}-auth.cfg.example
```

But what `%{__install}` actually is? Some kind of built-in macros for rpm builder? It's hard to google it or find it in the official docs, but it looks like it's a some kind of common thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no magical answer. Rpm macros can be redefined differently on different OS and can even be redefined afterwards by other packages.

Default definitions can be found in `/usr/lib/rpm/macros`, but other packages can install more macros in `/usr/lib/rpm/macros.d/`.

in my `/usr/lib/rpm/macros` if found this definition:

```
%__install              /usr/bin/install
```

so in this case the macro `%__install` doesn't really add anything.

But I find the `%make_install` macro rather handy; which is defined as:

```
%make_install %{__make} install DESTDIR=%{?buildroot} INSTALL="%{__install} -p"
```

so instead of putting

```
make install DESTDIR=%{?buildroot}
```

I can just put

```
%make_install
```

in my spec file... (and while explaining this; I just got to know the `-p` option of install :) )

Answer (score 5):

`%__install` is a macro.

If you want to get value of a macro, then use 'rpm --eval':

```
$ rpm --eval '%__install'
/usr/bin/install
$ rpm --eval '%{__install} -s %{name} %{buildroot}%{_sbindir}/'
/usr/bin/install -s %{name} /home/msuchy/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}.x86_64/usr/sbin/
```

In the second example, you can see that `%{name}` was not expanded, because that is not a system macro, but it is defined in the spec file by the `Name` tag.

Additionally, `rpm --showrc` shows you a list of system macros defined on your system. It shows the definition - not expanded macros.